# bison grammar,access returned variables

Tags: c, bison

```
block:
    "{" { //push scope;}
    multi_stmt
    "}" {
        //pop scope
        $$=new ASTNode_Block($2,..........)
     }
```

I'm trying to implement block structures in bison. However, I am having troubles here to access $2 (returned value from multi_stmt)

ps:  It's intended to not using "|" to separate them, thus i can have them executed in orders.

Answer (score 4):

Mid-rule actions also have numbers (but not, by default, return types). So the value of `multi_stmt` is `$3`, not `$2`.

`$1` is the open brace (which I think should be `'{'`, not `"{"` -- in bison, they are different --), `$2` is the mid-rule action, `$3` is `multi_stmt` and `$4` is the close brace.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing second `{` in line `"{" {`. If I understand correctly you intend to define a grammar rule `{ multi_stmt }`, so the second `{` is a mistake here.